# Why Am I Getting "Index Of /" On One Particular Page of My Local WAMP Site?

Tags: wamp

I'm running a Craft 3 CMS site locally using WAMP and all pages are loading properly, except for one page, my resources page, which kicks an "Index Of /" page that looks like the below:

[image]

Here are things that I know / have tried:

1. Adding /index.html after resources, makes the page load correctly
2. I set-up the exact same site in a separate local environment on the same computer, running the same WAMP instance, and that page loads properly
3. The page loads / works properly in production
4. All other pages on the site load properly, and child pages of /resources/ even load properly.
5. There is nothing unique about the page / underlying templates in this local environment vs. others

Why is this happening and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you have a folder that is also `resources`. Would deleting this folder fix the problem?

Comment: @Aziz Wow good call you're totally right! There was an empty resource folder in the site's root folder (separate from the templates folder, which is where the correct resources folder lives). It must have somehow accidentally got copied / pasted in there or something. Anyway, deleting it fixed the issue. If you want to put that as an official answer, I'd be happy to upvote / mark it correct. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had an empty folder called `resources`. The `Index of` page is showing the content of that folder. Deleting it fixes the problem.